Unity Android Build Error in version 2022.3.23f1
I want to build my game for Android but I get this error 2 times when it builds:
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.collections@2.1.4\Unity.Collections\NativeList.cs(837,24): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'safety' of 'NativeArray.ReadOnly.ReadOnly(void, int, ref AtomicSafetyHandle)'
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.collections@2.1.4\Unity.Collections\NativeList.cs(851,24): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'safety' of 'NativeArray.ReadOnly.ReadOnly(void, int, ref AtomicSafetyHandle)'
And If I press on them, they point me here
What can I do about it? I tried some fixes that I have found online but they don't work.. I have IL2CPP installed from Unity hub...





Have you tried building it with MonoIL instead of C++? There might be a third party package or library that you're using which is not properly built using IL2CPP.

I have allready tried it, it still won't work, I've tried everything but can't find the culprit for this error...

What packages are you using?

I've tried updating Collections to 2.1.4 or 2.4.0, it still does it https://imgur.com/a/VuLVite
